# Google Map shows and after 1 sec turns grey

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm getting confused while using google maps v3. 
I try to insert simple map with the code from google tutorials website.

```
        function initialize() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                    myOptions);
        }
```

Before that code I'm loading api javascript file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
    </script>
```

The problem is the map loads and for a while it turns grey. It does not matter if I set another zoom level, another center or etc, all options seems to be okay. The css is default, I'm not overriding it, just setting the width and height (in px). What can cause that problem?

Comment: The code you have provided works perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/Milanzor/JD72N/

Comment: The important part in your jsfiddle is probably the CSS which is not in the code that @Kamil has provided.  Kamil can we see your HTML and CSS too please?

Comment: Issue fixed - I found that the overflow: hidden was overriding divs inside the map, so @duncan - you were right about the CSS